# How to get the value of some special field out of a XML file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

The XML Yahoo! Weather API([example](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2459115)) has three fields named `link` in it of which two are same (specific forecast links) and the other is just "http://weather.yahoo.com".

How to get the specific value of any of those two in Javascript?
[image]

I have already done this in a function which gets just "http://weather.yahoo.com" one instead of the other links.

`weather.link = $($(data).find('link')[0]).text()`

Comment: I added jQuery tag since you are evidently using jQuery

Comment: What is your problem? You say you can already get one link, what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @musefan I am designing a weather application in which it will open a detailed Yahoo Weather forecast of the city in browser when the city name is clicked in the app. However it just opens `http://weather.yahoo.com` instead of something like `http://weather.yahoo.com/united-states/new-york/new-york-2459115/`

Comment: by doing this you may face Cross Domain issue (CORS)

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan What's that? http://weather.yahoo.com/united-states/new-york/new-york-2459115/ opens without any problems.

Comment: does `data` contain the full XML shown above? What does `$(data).find('link')` contain?

Comment: @musefan `$(data).find('link')` contains http://weather.yahoo.com but I want it to contain http://weather.yahoo.com/united-states/new-york/new-york-2459115/

Comment: `find()` will return multiple matches. Are you telling me it only contains one match? If so, then `data` surely does not contain all that XML you have posted... which is why I asked you to confirm. Either provide enough information, or create a JSFiddle that shows this problem in action

Comment: @musefan How to make a JSFiddle? And how to know which match it gets (I thought it only gets `http://weather.yahoo.com` because it hyperllinkes the text so)?

Comment: Google JSfiddle, fill in the boxes with HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT... is it really that complicated? `console.log(data)` will output all data to console, `console.log($(data).find('link'))` should output the collection of matches

Comment: @musefan `weather.link = $(data).filterNode('item').children().filterNode("link").text()` fixes the whole thing as it gets the text of the correct field. So I was using the correct whole XML.